# Python Sudoku - 2D array scoring function

Tags: python, arrays, sudoku

Suppose I have a simple 2d array representing a sudoku board

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0]
 [2 0 7 0 0 9 0 0 0]
 [6 0 0 3 5 1 0 0 0]
 [5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 8]
 [0 0 0 8 2 0 5 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 4]
 [0 0 6 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 8 0 0 0 0 7 0 0]]
```

I would like to write a function that returns a list of tuples containing x coordinate y coordinate and calculated score, for every cell that is 0. The score should be calculated as number of already filled positions in corresponding row, column and 3x3 box.

Let's say I'm iterating over the array and reached the point where I'm calculating the score for cell I've marked with X

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0]
 [2 X 7 0 0 9 0 0 0]
 [6 0 0 3 5 1 0 0 0]
 [5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 8]
 [0 0 0 8 2 0 5 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 4]
 [0 0 6 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 8 0 0 0 0 7 0 0]]
```

That iteration should count score for the cell marked X as 7 (1 (column) + 3(row) + 3(box)). And as a final step add the tuple into the list such as `(2, 2, 7)`

The fucntion should look like:

```
def scoreArray(grid):
```

and return structure like:

```
[0, 0, 3],
[0, 1, 4],
[0, 2, 6]
```

etc...
So far I did calculation for rows as following:

```
board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]
results = []

for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        if board[x][y] == 0:
            score = 0
            for g in range (9):
                    if board[g][x] != 0:
                            score += 1
            results.append((x,y,score))
            
print(results)
```

However, I'm unsure how to add column and 3x3 box scoring as well.

Answer (score 0):

For row and column:

```
board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]
results = []

score = 0
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        if board[x][y] == 0:
            for g in range (9):
                if board[x][g] != 0:
                    score += 1
            for a in range(9):
                if board[a][y] !=0:
                    score += 1
        results.append((x,y,score))
        score = 0

print(results)
```

And for the 3x3 part: Make an array (which will have 9 elements) (before the for loops). In this array will be the amounts of non-zero numbers in the 9 3x3 fields. You have to iterate 9 times for that. Example for the first one:

```
    thearray = []
    firstthreethree = 0
    for x in range(0, 2):
        for y in range(0,2): 
            if board[x][y] != 0: 
                firstthreethree += 1
    thearray.append(firstthreethree)
```

If you finished all nine 3x3 fields, you can check in the for loop in which of the 9 3x3 fields the current number is and then look up in the array you made how many non-zero numbers are in that field